# Parallelization of Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: c#, graph, parallel-processing, dijkstra

I'm trying to write concurrent solution for Dijkstra algorithm. My approach is to break the set of vertices into continuous blocks and each block is processed by another thread. In general the algorithm for each block is:

1. Find vertice with minimum weight of path to current global minimum among thread's vertices.
2. Sent local min verticle to main thread and wait for response.
3. After all threads sent their local minimums the main thread wakes up, finds new global minimum among locals, marks it as visited, broadcast it to all threads and starts to wait for a new local minimums.
4. Threads update weights from their verticles to global minimum and go to (1).

This algorithm repeats untill all local variables of thread are visited. Main threads exits when all working threads finished their work.

To implement this flow I use *ManulaResetEvent* objects.
However sometimes(like 1 of 20 runs) I've got wrong results and I cannot figure out why.

```
class Program
{
    private const int Size = 6;
    private const int FirstVertexIndex = 0;
    private const int MaxThreadsCount = 10;

    private static int[,] _graphMatrix = new int[Size, Size];

    private static ManualResetEvent _manualReset = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static int _currentSource = FirstVertexIndex;

    static Program()
    {
        //INIT ADJACENCY MATRIX
    }


    public static void Main()
    {

            for (var t = 1; t < MaxThreadsCount; t++)
            {
                //GC.Collect();

                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();

                Dijkstra(t);

                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Threads count: {t}; Average time: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
                sw.Reset();
            }


        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Dijkstra(int threadsCount)
    {
        var visited = new bool[Size];
        var weights = new int[Size];

        for(var i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            weights[i] = int.MaxValue;
        }

        weights[FirstVertexIndex] = 0;

        var values = new List<(int Index, int Weight)>();
        var threadReseters = new List<ManualResetEvent>();
        var threads = new List<Thread>();

        var step = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)Size / threadsCount);

        for(var t = 0; t < threadsCount; t++)
        {
            var start = t * step;

            if(start >= Size)
            {
                break;
            }

            var end = start + step;
            end = end >= Size ? Size : end;

            values.Add((0, 0));
            threadReseters.Add(new ManualResetEvent(false));
            var index = t;
            threads.Add(
                new Thread(
                    () => DoWork(
                        weights,
                        visited,
                        start,
                        end,
                        index,
                        threadReseters,
                        values)));
        }

        threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());

        while(threads.Any(t=> t.IsAlive || t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running || t.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin))
        {
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(threadReseters.ToArray());

            var globalMin = FindMin(values);

            if(_currentSource != -1)
                visited[_currentSource] = true;

            _currentSource = globalMin.Index;
            _manualReset.Set();
            _manualReset.Reset();

        }

        Console.WriteLine(PrintSolution(weights));
    }

    private static void DoWork(
        int[] weights,
        bool[] visited,
        int start,
        int end,
        int index,
        List<ManualResetEvent> threadReseters,
        List<(int Index, int Weight)> results)
    {

        while(true)
        {

                var min = MinNonVisitedIndex(
                    weights,
                    visited,
                    start,
                    end);

                results[index] = min;

                var visitedCount = 0;

                for (var i = start; i < end; i++)
                {
                    if (visited[i])
                    {
                        visitedCount++;
                    }
                }


                if (visitedCount == end - start)
                {
                    threadReseters[index]
                        .Set();

                    break;
                }

                threadReseters[index]
                    .Set();

                _manualReset.WaitOne();

                var localCurrentSource = _currentSource;

                threadReseters[index]
                    .Reset();


                ReweightPaths(
                    weights,
                    visited,
                    localCurrentSource,
                    start,
                    end);

            }

    }

    private static void ReweightPaths(
        int[] weights,
        bool[] visited,
        int current,
        int start,
        int end)
    {
        for(var i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            if(!visited[i]
               && _graphMatrix[current, i] != 0
               && weights[current] != int.MaxValue
               && weights[current] + _graphMatrix[current, i] < weights[i])
            {
                weights[i] = weights[current] + _graphMatrix[current, i];
            }
        }
    }

    private static (int Index, int Weight) MinNonVisitedIndex(
        int[] weights,
        bool[] visited,
        int from,
        int to)
    {
        var min = int.MaxValue;
        var minIndex = -1;

        for(var i = from; i < to; i++)
        {
            if(!visited[i] && weights[i] < min)
            {
                min = weights[i];
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }

        return (minIndex, minIndex != -1 ? weights[minIndex] : Int32.MaxValue);
    }

    private static (int Index, int Weight) FindMin(List<(int Index, int Weight)> values)
    {
        lock (o)
        {
            var min = (Index: -1, Weight: int.MaxValue);

            for(int i = 0; i<values.Count; i++)
            {
                if(min.Weight > values[i].Weight)
                {
                    min.Weight = values[i].Weight;
                    min.Index = values[i].Index;
                }
            }

            return min;
        }
    }

    private static string PrintSolution(int[] weights)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(var i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            sb.Append($"{i + 1}\t\t{weights[i]}");
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

static class MatrixExtensions
{
    public static string Print<T>(this T[,] seq)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(var i = 0; i < seq.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for(var j = 0; j < seq.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                sb.Append($"{seq[i, j].ToString()} ");
            }

            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Please, check http://parallelcomp.uw.hu/ch10lev1sec3.html . That's what I'm trying to implement, but in this code I have something like race condition somewhere and I cannot figure out where and why

Comment: I do not think it can work with a graph that contains loops.  Dijkstra requires setting a visited bit (and you need to reset the bit after a path fails) which will not work when attempting in parallel unless you have cloned copies of the graph (one for each parallel thread).

Comment: If it will work, it is no dijkstra algorithm anymore. In Dijkstra, the order of visiting vertices is important. In the original Dijkstra algorithm the only thing that can be parallelized is the recomputing of the neigbour vertices while visiting a vertex. The use of parallal threads could be profitable when using a shortest path search algorithm for partioned graphs, p.e. arcflags (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1017.5213&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: @jdweng Why a path should fail? It is a greedy algorithm. Pls, check http://parallelcomp.uw.hu/ch10lev1sec3.html and http://parallelcomp.uw.hu/ch10lev1sec2.html#ch10lev1sec2 That's what I am trying to implement